# Split String at specific character

Tags: javascript, function, split

I have the following code:

```
var string = "word1;word2;word3,word4,word5,word6.word7";

function ends_with(string, character) {
  var regexp = new RegExp('\\w+' + character, 'g');
  var matches = string.match(regexp);
  var replacer = new RegExp(character + '$');
  return matches.map(function(ee) {
    return ee.replace(replacer, '');
  });
}
// ends_with(string, ';') => ["word1", "word2"]
```

The function takes no regard to whitespace. For example if you input

```
ends_with('Jonas Sand,', ',')
```

the output will be Sand. Need help on making the function work with words that has whitespace.

Comment: Please put your code in code blocks - CTRL+K :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use your separator within [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and take all except the last part with [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

```
function ends_with(string, character) {
    return string.split(character).slice(0, -1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`\w` matches word characters, use `[^x]` instead, where `x` is your character. This matches everything but your character.

So the first line in your function becomes

```
var regexp = new RegExp('[^' + character + "]+" + character, 'g');
```

on the other hand, if you want to match words separated by white space, use

```
var regexp = new RegExp('(\\w|\\s)+" + character, 'g');
```

PS: *but isn't there a `String#split` function in javascript?*

Answer (score 1):

Try using `'[\\w\\s]+'` instead of `'\\w+'` to include whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
var string = "word1;w ord2;word3,word4,word5,word6.word7";

function ends_with(string, character) {
    var regexp = new RegExp('.+' + character, 'g');
    var matches = string.match(regexp);
    var replacer = new RegExp(character + '$');
    return matches.map(function(ee) {
        return ee.replace(replacer, '');
    });
}
```